# SQL Server : increment number w/ constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table that will create a ID for customers that is a number starting at 101 and increasing by 1 for each customer. So the first customer will have the ID 101, the second will have 102 and so on. In addition to the ID I have other information namely First and Last names. I have also added a constraint that applies to the first and last name columns that will force the entries to be made up by letters.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tblcustomer 
(
    CUST_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(101,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT firstlet CHECK (FIRST_NAME NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%' 
                               AND LAST_NAME NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')
);
```

This works as intended except for one small issue. When I try to insert say a number for the first name, the constraint will work and not enter anything to the table. But then when I insert the first and last name correctly, it will add the information to the table but the CUST_ID will skip a number.

Example Inserts:

```
insert into tblcustomer(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) values ('Bob','Smith');
insert into tblcustomer(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) values ('Greg','Johns');
insert into tblcustomer(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) values ('Todd','123');
insert into tblcustomer(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) values ('Todd','Howe');
```

Output:

```
CUST_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
-----------------------------
101     Bob         Smith
102     Greg        Johns
104     Todd        Howe
```

So where the `CUST_ID` shows 104 should actually be 103.

Comment: The IDENTITY will keep increasing even meets error. For your case, you probably need to do RESEED to keep the CUST_ID in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An identity column value gets updated the moment it receives a request. Hence even when the insertion fails due to validation constraints, the number is already taken.

If your business case requires exact sequence of ID being generated (preserving order of insertion), you will need to set the value of ID column manually using identity_insert as on, then increment the max ID. Do note that if multiple such request come, there can be race conditions where 2 records with same ID are tried to be inserted, and second fails due to primary की constraint.

If all you want with the primary key being unique automatically, use a Guid field. That will save you from all this effort.

Answer (score 2):

Skipping a number is fine. It's normal behavior in any database, and you shouldn't expect the numbers to remain consecutive forever. If this bothers you, try using a GUID key instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example, you are using `sequence` for an auto increment. With `begin transaction` inserting a record into the table. But any how you just `rollback` that transaction.
so next `insert` will skip that transaction, because it will not hold or place the lock on the `sequence`.
`Sequence` will just raise the identity, its job done, If you want to use it or not. and as best practice its good and healthy for performance purpose.